Duplicate rows and change the values of a column in a dataframe in R
I need your help.
I have a dataframe like this



city
value




city1
15


city2
20



I need to duplicate city1 4 times and city2 5 times, this values are fixed.But then I need to change the value of city so that the dataframe looks like this:



city
value




city1
15


city3
15


city4
15


city5
15


city2
20


city6
20


city7
20


city8
20


city9
20



I currently have this code for duplication, but I am missing the final step, I need someone who can help me with this.
df %>%
  mutate(ncity = if_else(cod_ubicacion == "city1", 4, 5)) %>%
  slice(rep(seq_len(n()), ncity))


I'm curious about the context for this, if you wouldn't mind sharing. It's a surprise to me to have a category name like city1 where it seems only the numeric part means anything, and it needs to be ordered in a specific way. It would make a little more sense to me if it was just a numeric variable city_num, but even then... what conditions make this the desired behavior?

This is kludgey, but at least I think it's pretty clear what it's doing.
Take the data, separate city into character and numeric components, copy each line as many times as desired, then flag the originals (first row of each city number), then change the others to be a cumulative sequence starting after the last original city, and then just show the combined cities and values.
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(city = c("city1", "city2"), value = c(15, 20)) |>
  separate(city, c("stub", "num"), convert = TRUE,
           sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])") |>
  uncount(c(4,5)) |>
  mutate(new = row_number() != 1, .by = num) |>
  mutate(num = if_else(new, max(num) + cumsum(1*new), num)) |>
  transmute(city = paste0(stub, num), value)

   city value
1 city1    15
2 city3    15
3 city4    15
4 city5    15
5 city2    20
6 city6    20
7 city7    20
8 city8    20
9 city9    20


Great answer by @Jon Spring. Another option with the tidyverse:
### Packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

### Data
data=data.frame(city = c("city1", "city2"), value = c(15, 20))

### Duplicate the rows
df = data %>%
  uncount(weights = c(4,5)) %>% group_by(city)

### Keep the first row of each city group
df0 = df %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(rk=row_number())

### Associate the remaining rows with a specific value
df1 = df %>%
  slice(-1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(rk=(nrow(df0)+1):nrow(df))

### Bind and arrange
out = bind_rows(df0,df1) %>%
  arrange(city,rk) %>% 
  mutate(city=paste0("city",rk)) %>% 
  select(city,value)

Output :
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  city  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 city1    15
2 city3    15
3 city4    15
4 city5    15
5 city2    20
6 city6    20
7 city7    20
8 city8    20
9 city9    20

